# Text in span disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a main menu that is a list. On the last item of this list a append a class 'navitemsearch'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cf li:last-child span').addClass('navitemsearch');
    $('.cf li:last-child a').attr('id', 'link');
    $('#link').attr('href', '#');

    $('.navitemsearch').click(function() {
        $('#searchAreaDiv').slideToggle();       
    })
    return false;   
});
```

The HTML then looks like this:

```
<div id="nav-main">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> 
  <li></li> 
  <li></li>  
  <li><a href="#" id="link"><span class="navitemsearch">Sök</span></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="searchAreaDiv">....</div>
```

My problem is that efter clicking 'navitemsearch' the text 'Sök' in the  disappears.
After click any where on the page the text 'Sök' is there again.

What can i do to **not** make it disappear when clicking the link?

Comment: Remove the slide toggle?

Comment: I need to have the slidetoggle.

Comment: I don't see how the text is vanishing from what you've posted. Can you post more of the HTML? Are you saying the text toggles on click because maybe your click event item is within the div being toggled?

Answer (score 1):

This *maybe* happens because of the `slideToggle()` here:

```
 $('.navitemsearch').click(function() {
     $('#searchAreaDiv').slideToggle();       
 })
```

You are telling that every time you click class `navitemsearch` the whole search area should toggle (show/hide). Since you add this class to your `span`, it will call the event handler and toggle the `searchAreaDiv` every time you click it.

Comment: I see. but my navitemsearch is not in my searchAreaDiv? I'm just telling it to show/hide searchAreaDiv?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have some conflicting JavaScript which toggles the text? Can you create a jsFiddle with this scenario?